# Sending HD movie frames through sockets to Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets, video

I was wondering if someone has ever done something like this. I have a HD movie (or even 720p one) and I want to send it to a Flash client. I was thinking of using OpenCV in C++ for the decoding and sending part. I had even implemented some of this, but have problems with wrong packet size.

But my question is different, has anyone did anything similar to this? Can this give a chance for performance improvement? I have strong doubts about this, because I think the sending and decoding will be still difficult for the Flash machine. Looking forward to hearing some opinions from more experienced guys.

Answer (score 0):

not a real answer, more like thoughts about your problem:

- yes, you *must* encode HD images, sending 25 fps x 1.5mb over the net is a no-go.
- gstreamer was build for exactly that purpose. complicated, maybe, but look at it anyway !
- why write a program, when vlc can do all of this already ? (even headless/scripted!)
- if there's audio to stream, too - forget opencv. it's a computer-vision lib, not build for your problem there

Comment: I'm seeking thoughts and different points of view here so thanks ;-) You noticed the lack of sound when using OpenCV - that can be a problem, I must take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two network protocols that are commonly used to send video from a server to a flash client, HTTP, and RTMP.

HTTP is a well-known standard, easily implemented because it is a plain-text protocol, that allows Flash Player to play on-demand video files, or do what is called [pseudo-streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash/).

RTMP is a proprietary protocol created by Adobe, that allows real-time streaming as well as video on demand, and can also transport structured binary data (the AMF format) to act as a remote procedure call protocol.
Although now documented, it is much more complicated to implement than HTTP, but there is an open-source library that implements this protocol, librtmp, found at http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/.

Please note that I have used librtmp with success, on the client side, to have a C program act as a Flash client to publish video on a FMS server. I have no experience of using it on the server side, I don't even know if it's possible at all.

In your case I certainly recommend using HTTP.

Now there is another problem to overcome, it is the fact that for video frames to be properly recognized, they must be embedded in a container that the Flash player can read.

Flash currently supports two container formats, FLV and F4V, the latter being a subset of the MPEG-4 container format.

Also, the video stream must be readable by Flash, and so it must be properly encoded into a format supported on the client-side, for example H.264, Sorensen, or VP6.

It is possible to directly send GIF, JPEG or PNG images as frames, as seen on page 8 of the official [Flash Video Specification](http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf), but you must realize that in a HD resolution, this will be extremely inefficient, just imagine that at 25 FPS, a single image at 1920x1080 pixels in JPEG is much bigger than the equivalent H.264 frame.

So, in the end, my advice is: **do not decode the video** on the server, make sure it is in a format compatible with Flash, and use a well-documented protocol to send it as-is.

Comment: Your answer helped me realize that it seems like an even worst way. I were looking to improve performance of my Flash application in which I want to play 3 or 4 HD videos. Using everything I found natively in Flash I still haven't found anything to support with an acceptable quality. Though this may do it - seems I was wrong